# Traditional animation software

Tags: macos, animation

I'm creating an animation by drawing each frame (thanks to Onion Skinning). Do you know if there is a Mac app which can help me compose the video by importing images as frames? 
I do not want to use a different application to draw *and* animate.

I would like to change a few settings, if possible (e.g. number of frames per second).

You may want to write one suggestion and let users vote on each answer.

Thank you in advance.
—Alberto

Comment: Something like [iStopMotion](http://www.boinx.com/istopmotion/overview/)? (Not sure if this is what you want, so it's just a comment for now)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[iStopMotion](http://www.boinx.com/istopmotion/overview/) might be something like what you want.